# Why do some people build app from CMD using Gradle, instead of just clicking the Run button in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Is there any hidden benefit of doing that?
I am just watching this Android Studio + Gradle tutorial and it seems like a lot of work to build from the command line:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-k6dpfXqBY

***If the question is not quality enough, can you point me to a place where asking it would be appropriate, instead of downvoting, and I will delete it myself.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the app from the IDE does just that: runs the app from the IDE.

Gradle is a full task-based build system. There are *many* more tasks that can be run from Gradle than just what an IDE's "run" button does. Personally, I have Gradle tasks that:

- package up JAR editions of library modules that do not need resources, as a distribution option for Eclipse users
- publishes AARs to a local Maven repo, for later upload to my public Maven repo
- publishes JavaDocs (though, um, I need to do more than this)

And I'm just barely scratching the surface of what's possible. Let alone more enterprise-y scenarios like running Gradle tasks from build servers or CI servers.

Also, please bear in mind that not everyone uses an IDE. Developers are welcome to use a text editor and the command line for most of their Android development.

Comment: Of course, the whole point of Android Studio is that your run button could do all those same tasks (or you could have multiple Gradle run configurations that each do one of these things): anything available on the command line is also available in the IDE and vice versa.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Eminently true. However, some of us suffer from a chronic condition referred to as "old". This malady is known to sometimes cause hair loss, weak vision, and other physical effects. It is also prone to cause afflicted developers to prefer using the command line in some cases, occasionally while muttering something about lawns. :-)

Comment: So im not missing out on anything if I run app from the RUN button? Also, in Eclipse, whenever I ran the app, an APK file is created in the BIN directory of the project, so I got that file and sent it to interested parties. I cannot find an APK file whenever I run from Android Studio, though. Where is it?

Comment: @J.K.: "So im not missing out on anything if I run app from the RUN button?" -- for the basic task of running an app, no. Note that you can use the Build Variants tool (docked by default on the left edge) to control which build variant is the one that actually runs (e.g., debug vs. release). "I cannot find an APK file whenever I run from Android Studio, though" -- generally, the outputs are in `build/outputs/`. APKs will be in `build/outputs/apk/`.